# Thymeleaf creating and sending multipart form object by itself to controller even though user is not selecting any file

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, multipartform-data, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to upload a Multipart file using Thymeleaf and spring boot,
but even though I am not selecting any file to upload after clicking on Submit button Thymeleaf is creating and sending the Object to controller by itself.

Upload Image:

```
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Android:</label>
                                <li>
                                    <input type='file' id='android' class="uploadimge" name="android"  onchange="readURL(event, this)" />

                                </li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Cancel

My Controller Code is Here -

```
    @RequestMapping("/saveCategory")
    public String saveCategory(@ModelAttribute("saveCategory") MultipartFile android,HttpServletRequest request,Model model){
        System.out.println("In Controller saveCategory() "+android);


        // code to perform operation on File. .     

         return "redirect:category";
}
```

The message it is printing on Console After clicking on Submit button (even when I'm not selecting and uploading any image) is  :-

org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@14de417d